# getting error in EDGE and IE11 Object doesn't support property or method 'waitUntil'" using method in service-worker.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

Getting Object doesn't support property or method 'waitUntil'" error while calling in service-worker.js file(in Edge and IE11)

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

Comment: I don't think IE11 supports the service worker stuff at all.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer was deprecated before service workers were created. So dont worry about it, at all. MSFT has not supported it for like 5 years and neither should you.

Edge has supported service workers, including waitUntil for a few years.

So I don't think you are having the issue in Edge. If the service worker registers then waitUntil works, it is part of the spec.